# Why doesn't compiler error on build?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, option-strict, option-explicit

I am using VB.NET, at the top is

```
Option Explicit
```

However why does the compiler not raise an error when I do :-

```
obj.ThisFunction(Convert.ToInt32(strMessage))
```

and the function is :-

```
Function ThisFunction(id as long)
```

Surely, Int32 is int and int64 is long?  Is there a compiler option in VS 2013 that I can turn on to spot these?

Comment: VB.NET compiler automatically convert Int32 to long.

Comment: If you want to spot type errors, use `OPTION STRICT ON`. But implicit integer to long conversion is still allowed.

Comment: Yes, the value in strMessage can now be very long and Convert.ToInt32 will cause a run time error.  It'll be a nightmare going through all the code looking for and upsizing every ToInt32.  If I can do that easily with an error list, that'll be good.  Strict was on as well :(

Comment: Since your `strMessage` variable  won't be populated until runtime, how do you expect the compiler to catch that error?  The compiler has absolutely no way to know what will be in that variable.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a compile error. If you have written code to *explicitly* convert `strMessage` to an `Int32`, then the compiler assumes you knew what you were doing here.

In order to check this is actually an `Int32` you can use `Int32.TryParse`

Converting an `Int32` to an `Int64` is not a compile error even with `Option Strict On` because this is a *widening* conversion (Option Strict On gives a compilation error when it finds *implicit narrowing* conversions, amongst other things)